# how to make a count of records in a Room Database, using jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I have an issue which I could use some help.
I have a Room database in a jetpack compose project. I am trying to get the count of some records that meet certain criteria.
I have been following all directions that I have found; although there are no examples that go all the way thru to the result of a **count query**. All I have found is the DAO and the expalantions end there.
So here is what I have tried and hopefully some kind sould will tell what I'm doing wrong and how to remedy the situation.

This is the DAO, which I think is correct?:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grocery_table WHERE checkChecked = 1")
 fun getShoppingItems(): Int
```

Then there is a Sealed Interfase; not sure if that is relevant to the answer.
The last data class is the one involved in this issue:

```
sealed interface GroceriesEvent {

data class SetItemName(val itemName: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetMarket(val market: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetDepartment(val department: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetBrand(val brand: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetSize(val size: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetPrice(val price: String): GroceriesEvent
data class SetDate(val date: String): GroceriesEvent
data class UpdateItemName(val id:Int, val itemName: String):GroceriesEvent
data class SetCheckToAdd(val id: Int, val checkToAdd: Boolean): GroceriesEvent
data class SetCardCheck(val id: Int, val checkToAdd: Boolean):GroceriesEvent
data class SetCheckChecked(val id: Int, val checkChecked: Boolean): GroceriesEvent
object SaveItem: GroceriesEvent
data class SortGroceries(val sortType: SortType): GroceriesEvent
data class DeleteItem(val groceries: Groceries): GroceriesEvent
data class UpdateItem(val id: Int): GroceriesEvent
data class FindById(val  id:Int):GroceriesEvent

// -----  THIS ONE ----
data class InShoppingCart(val Purchased: Int):GroceriesEvent
```

Then the UISTATE. The last **var** is the one used for this issue:

```
data class GroceriesState(
var id: Int = 0,
val groceries: List<Groceries> = emptyList(),
val itemName: String = "",
val market: String = "",
val department: String = "",
val brand: String = "",
val size: String = "",
val price: String = "",
val date: String = "",
val checkToAdd: Boolean = false,
val checkChecked: Boolean = false,
val sortType: SortType = SortType.CHECK_TO_ADD,
var idForItemUpdate:Int = 0,
var addOrEdit: Boolean = false,
var purchased: Int = 0
```

)

Then the **ViewModel**. I am only displaying the part that involves this. If more is needed, please let me know: (it is enclosed in a **WHEN** statement

```
is GroceriesEvent.InShoppingCart -> {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                dao.getShoppingItems()
            }
        }
```

Lastly in the composable:

```
onEvent(GroceriesEvent.InShoppingCart(state.purchased))
```

The result of all of this is: the project compiles and runs; then when I navigate to the screen that has that **onEvent**, it crashes.

I am making the assumption that the above enEvent is formulated properly; that is that the **state.purchased** is the location where the count is stored (not a parameter).
Why does it crash? I don't know. I don't know enough for figure it out from the logs.

Any help is greatly aprreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the crash log? Unrelated to your crash—you can’t have `var` properties in your GroceriesState class or it won’t work correctly with Compose. The reason is that Compose State works by comparing old and new values. It cannot compare values correctly to determine when to recompose if the property within the old value is mutable.

Comment: thank you @Tenfour04. I will follow your advise about the **var** and then post the crash log

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea you may implement to solve your problem, I don't know whether this will help you or not. Since I am a beginner in the field of app developments.

1. Try making your DAO and the place where you had used it, a coroutine function. Use suspend or flow etc.
2. Check in which thread you operation is being performed.
3. Check whether you database is created correctly or not. Because if it is not created correctly it will give you the error as null value or empty.(Side Note: I am also facing maybe the same issue, right now. That's why I am suggesting this tips to help).
   Well I don't know when I will get the solution of my problem, But I hope these pointers may solve your problem. If you want more clarity from me, please feel free to ask and also share relavant code.

Thanks for reading my Comment.

Sorry, I want to add one more thing try running debugger on the DAO function that inserts the value to the database and check whether you get the desired output for your variable. And using logging at the place where you executed fetchUser(or something like that) function of dao. It may be viewModel or Repository.